# Android overdraw background. How set correctly?

Tags: android, performance, background

I know there are many topics with the same request but I can not fix the background problem for my application.
If I write the code like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top|center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background:"@drawable/wallpaper>
```

I receive the error Lint: "**Possible overdraw: Root element paints the background....**"

So I changed with this:

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="WallpaperTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/wallpaper</item>
</style>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/WallpaperTheme">
        ...
        ...
    </activity>
```

In this way no longer receiving the error Lint but the layout of the application is wrong, for example:
[image]
Also the buttons do not follow the correct layout ...
How do I do then?

Answer (score 2):

I'm stupid!
I changed the code in this way, and the error of Lint no longer appears:

**style.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            ...
            ...
        </activity>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="top"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to change the app theme ? It seems to me that you just wanna change the background of the activity and put the layout background as the activity background... Why do you

1. change app theme ?
2. change windowBackground and not only the background ?

Here, you basically change the container/parent of the layout itself by setting it to a null decorview. You don't need this and that is what affects the placement of the linear layout.